# Multiple file upload in asp.net core is not working

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, razor, data-annotations

I am working on .net core 3.1. My problem is when I try to upload multiple files it is picking only the file which I have uploaded latest. For egg, when I upload 3 files only the third file is coming into the controller.

My model:

```
public class ProductModel
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Product Name is Required")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Atleast one category need to be selected")]
        public int[] ProductCategoryIds { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Needs to have any brand")]
        public int? BrandId { get; set; }

        public string BrandName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Tax is Required")]
        public int? TaxId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Product Price is Required")]
        public decimal? ProductPrice { get; set; }

        public string ProductModels { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Available quantity is Required")]
        public  int? AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

        public string StockStatus { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image is Required")]
        [ValidateFile(ErrorMessage ="Invalid File Type")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.png|.jpg|.JPG|.PNG)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid File types")]
        public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }

        public string ProductImagePath { get; set; }

        public List<IFormFile> AdditionalImages { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public string ColorAttribute { get; set; }

        public int? DiscountProductCount1 { get; set; }
        public int? DiscountProductCount2 { get; set; }
        public int? DiscountProductCount3 { get; set; }

        public int[] AttributesId { get; set; }

        public string AttributesAsString { get; set; }

        public decimal? DiscountProductPrice1 { get; set; }
        public decimal? DiscountProductPrice2 { get; set; }
        public decimal? DiscountProductPrice3 { get; set; }

        public string DiscountJson { get; set; }

        public decimal? ProductPriceOffer { get; set; }

        public int? MinimumQuantity { get; set; }

        public List<ProductImageModel> ProductImageList { get; set; }

        public List<CategoryModel> CategoryList { get; set; }

        public TaxModel Tax { get; set; }

        public List<TaxModel> TaxList { get; set; }

        public List<AttributesModel> AttributesList { get; set; }

        public List<ProductDiscountModel> DiscountsList { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

My cshtml:

```
 <form asp-action="NewProducts" asp-controller="Product" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label>Product Additional Image</label>
                   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="AdditionalImages" asp-for="Product.AdditionalImages" multiple 
                        placeholder="Product Additional Image">
                   
                </div>
</form>
```

My controller, when I submits only the latest file is coming into the  controller:

```
public IActionResult NewProducts(ProductModel product)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    product.AttributesAsString = GetAttributesAsJson(product);
                    product.DiscountJson = GetDiscountsAsJson(product);
                    //saving general and category details of product
                    ProductModel results = _product.SaveProductGeneral(product);
                    product.ProductId = results.ProductId;
                    List<ProductImageModel> images= GetProductImages(product);
                    
                    //saving all images
                    //string allImagesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(images);
                    foreach(var image in images)
                    {
                        _product.SaveProductImages(image);
                    }
                    
                    ViewData["SuccessFormMessage"] = "Created Successfully";
                    ViewData["ErrorFormMessage"] = string.Empty;
                    ModelState.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["SuccessFormMessage"] = string.Empty;
                    ViewData["ErrorFormMessage"] = "Check all Required Fields";
                }

                ProductViewModel container = new ProductViewModel();
                container.Heading = new HeadingModel();
                container.Heading.MainHeading = "Product Management";
                container.Heading.SubHeading = "Addd new products for your store";
                ViewData["BrandDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_brand.GetAllBrandsByType("Active"), null, "brand");
                ViewData["TaxDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_tax.GetAllTaxesForDropDown("product"), null, "tax");
                ViewData["CategoryDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_category.GetCategoriesByStatus("Active").Where(x => x.Level == 1).ToList(), null, "category");
                ViewData["StatusDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_common.GetAllActiveStatus(), null, "status");
                ViewData["AttributesDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_attributes.GetAllAttributes(), null, "attributes");
                return View(container);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _common.SaveErrorLog(ex.ToString());
                ProductViewModel container = new ProductViewModel();
                container.Heading = new HeadingModel();
                container.Heading.MainHeading = "Product Management";
                container.Heading.SubHeading = "Addd new products for your store";
                ViewData["BrandDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_brand.GetAllBrandsByType("Active"), null, "brand");
                ViewData["TaxDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_tax.GetAllTaxesForDropDown(string.Empty), null, "tax");
                ViewData["CategoryDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_category.GetCategoriesByStatus("Active").Where(x => x.Level == 1).ToList(), null, "category");
                ViewData["StatusDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_common.GetAllActiveStatus(), null, "status");
                ViewData["AttributesDropDown"] = CommonUtils.CommonUtils.GetDropDownByType(_attributes.GetAllAttributes(), null, "attributes");
                ViewData["SuccessFormMessage"] = string.Empty;
                ViewData["ErrorFormMessage"] = "Something went wrong in our end";
                return View(container);
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add your code as text, not images.

Comment: Can you share code about your controller?

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is demo about getting files, you can refer to it.

MutiController:

```
public class MutiController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(MultipleFile multipleFile)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Index

```
@model MultipleFile
    
     <form asp-action="Index"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Photo" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input type="file"   asp-for="Photo" class="form-control"  multiple />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Photo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
                  </form>
```

MultipleFile:

```
 public class MultipleFile
    {
        [Key]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @barath thangam        In your  `asp-for="Product.AdditionalImages" ` , what is `Product`? In your `ProductModel` you already define the `AdditionalImages`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPut("MultiFileUpload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MultiFileUpload(IFormFileCollection collectionfile, string productcode)
    {
        APIResponse response = new APIResponse();
        int passcount = 0;
        int errorcount = 0;

        try
        {
            var filePath = GetFilePath(productcode);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }

            foreach (var file in collectionfile)
            {
                var ImagePath = filePath + "\\" + file.FileName;

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(ImagePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(ImagePath);
                }
                using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Create(ImagePath))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    passcount++;
                }
            }

            // Set response properties for success
            response.ResponseCode = 200;
            response.Result = $"Successfully uploaded {passcount} files.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorcount++;

            // Set response properties for error
            response.IsError = true;
            response.Error = new ApiResponseError
            {
                ErrorCode = "1001",
                ErrorDescription = "File upload failed.",
                SysErrorDescription = ex.Message // Add more details if needed
            };
            response.ResponseCode = 500;
        }

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**